# How to show textbox label name on Validation Summary

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Here's an input example with some validators

Validation Summary

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" 
    ID="ValidationSummary1"  
    DisplayMode="BulletList"                         
    ValidationGroup="vgInformacaoInicial"
    CssClass="alert validation-summary"
    ShowSummary="true" /> 

<div class="form-group col-8 mx-auto text-center">
    <asp:Label ID="lblCliente" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtCliente" Text="Cliente" />
    <small><i class="fas fa-asterisk text-danger mb-2" style="font-size: 7px;"></i></small>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliente" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" placeholder="Cliente" />
    <div class="valid-feedback feedback-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback feedback-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCliente" runat="server"  
        CssClass="server-validator" 
        ValidationGroup="vgInformacaoInicial" 
        SetFocusOnError="True" 
        ControlToValidate="txtCliente" 
        ErrorMessage="<b>Client:</b> Required Field." 
        Display="None">
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

Here is the problem, I want to show required field under every textbox and also on the Validation summary. This already does. Thing is, it's a mess and says Required field many times without any identification so I added the name in the required field error message but it becomes too long when it's under the textbox.

So short and simple... Is there a way i can show the label name referred by the validator on validation summary without having to write on error message and set display to none?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set `ErrorMessage` property of each validator to just the corresponding label name, and also set the `HeaderText` property of validation summary control to something like "Please input following fields:".

The same code snippet that you posted is modified with these changes as below.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" 
    ID="ValidationSummary1"  
    DisplayMode="BulletList"                         
    ValidationGroup="vgInformacaoInicial"
    CssClass="alert validation-summary"
    HeaderText="Please input following fields:"
    ShowSummary="true" /> 

<div class="form-group col-8 mx-auto text-center">
    <asp:Label ID="lblCliente" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtCliente" Text="Cliente" />
    <small><i class="fas fa-asterisk text-danger mb-2" style="font-size: 7px;"></i></small>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCliente" runat="server" CssClass="form-control form-control-sm rounded border border-dark" placeholder="Cliente" />
    <div class="valid-feedback feedback-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback feedback-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </div>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCliente" runat="server"  
        CssClass="server-validator" 
        ValidationGroup="vgInformacaoInicial" 
        SetFocusOnError="True" 
        ControlToValidate="txtCliente" 
        ErrorMessage="Cliente" 
        Display="None">
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

You will end up with a validation summary that looks like what is shown below.

[image: Validation Summary with just field labels]